# Difference between appending a list vs appending list[:]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

I am trying to traverse into a string using DFS and appending it to result in the line highlighted. However if I use `result.append(currlist)` vs `result.append(currlist[:])`, the result is totally different. The former doesn't work, why is that?

```
class Solution: 
       
    def dfs(self, start, s, currlist, result):
        if start >= len(s):
            result.append(currlist[:])  # <--
            return
        
        for end in range(start, len(s)):
            currlist.append(s[start:end+1])
            self.dfs(end+1, s, currlist, result)
            currlist.pop()
        
    def partition(self, s: str) -> List[List[str]]:
        result = []
        self.dfs(0, s, [], result)
        return result
```

Comment: `xs[:]` creates a copy of the list.

Comment: Related: [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list[:]` creates a copy of the object

Example:

```
x = []
y = [0, 1]

x.append(y)
print(x)

y[0] = 2

print(x)
```

Output:

> ```
> [[0, 1]]
> [[2, 1]]
> ```

```
x = []
y = [0, 1]

x.append(y[:])
print(x)

y[0] = 2

print(x)
```

Output:

> ```
> [[0, 1]]
> [[0, 1]]
> ```